# Get text property in a word table using Vb.net WinForms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ms-word

I have a VB.net application in WinFoms that can get the properties of cell in a word tables. The problem is it only gets the property of the cell and not the property per character.

For example, the line below is in a single cell.

> **The** *quick* <strike>brown</strike> **f** *o* <strike>x</strike>

How can I get the property of those?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the range of each word (or character) and check its font:

```
Dim cell As Word.Cell = tb.Cell(row, col);
Dim cellRng As Word.Range = cell.Range;
```

You can loop each word this way:

```
For Each rngWord As Word.Range In cellRng.Words
    If rngWord.Bold
        '...
    End If
Next
```

Be sure to add:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
```